# Is there any dedicated research group which is working in energy efficient cryptographic functions?

Tags: encryption, lightweight

Is there any dedicated research group which is working in energy efficient cryptographic functions for mobile devices.

In mobile devices other than tuning a frequency/voltage, network speed any other approach is available?

Comment: There is lightweight cryptography, which deals with cryptography for tiny devices like sensors.

Comment: This is pretty **broad** and somewhat a **list-type question** (which would both be off-topic). To limit things down and to prevent collecting even more downvotes, you might want to edit your question to describe **what research you did and what you found.** That shows you took time trying to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more relevant, on-point answers. At worst it might help you frame [“a better question”](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask); at best it might even answer it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

For low energy usage, google for research groups focusing on lightweight cryptography. See Section 3 of http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/ir/2017/NIST.IR.8114.pdf for NIST's contributions to Lightweight Cryptography.

For lowering network traffic, you really need to be more specific about what area of cryptography you are interested in (I.e. what is the goal). There are compression functions, but that is not cryptography. There is ongoing research into cryptosystems with smaller key and signature size, which lowers network traffic. Elliptic Curves for example require less data to be sent over the network for the same level of security compared to other asymmetric algorithms and digital signature algorithms. Work is correctly being done to improve/create Proof of Secure Erasure schemes that require less network traffic. This is not an exhaustive list, please be more specific about which area you are interested in, for specific answers about research groups. Google for groups performing research on lowering network traffic / required communicated data in the sub-area of cryptography you are interested in to find such research groups.

To answer your question about Mobile Devices, there is nothing special about a Mobile Device for these purposes. What you are really looking for is research groups making newer cryptographic algorithms and revising/improving current cryptographic algorithms to be more energy efficient in software implementations.

For the network traffic, there is again nothing special about mobile devices.